# learning mysql, JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm a beginner on MYSQL db and i'm trying to play around with the query and relations.

i have created 2 tables, one is 'users' which contain the field staff_ID and the other is 'reports' which also contain the table field staff_ID of the user submitting the reports.

on the relations (see picture) i have connect the 2 staff id field.

[image: relation]

every user can submit more than one reports, so i'm try to query and get only the reports of one users(staff_ID).
I understood i have to use the JOIN keyword in order to obtain the data..

i tried the following query but it gave me all the result for all the users.

```
SELECT u.staff_ID
     , u.Name
     , r.id_report_show
     , r.date_report 
  FROM users u
  JOIN reports r 
    ON r.staff_ID = u.staff_ID
```

but I would like to have the report only of one specific user like staff_ID = 04033

probably i understood wrong how this query JOIN work, i'm looking for some help.

Thanks

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause to filter the result-set. I.e. `WHERE staff_ID = 4033`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Your join is perfect. You just need a where clause.

```
    SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report 
    FROM `users` INNER JOIN reports ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID
    where users.staff_ID = 04033
```

Or you can also mention it within on clauses:

```
      SELECT users.staff_ID, users.Name, reports.id_report_show, reports.date_report 
      FROM `users` INNER JOIN reports 
      ON reports.staff_ID = users.staff_ID and users.staff_ID = 04033
```

Since it's inner join both the query will produce same output. But for left join those might produce different result. It's a good practice to use where clause instead of mentioning the condition in on clause.